# updating jsx with the response of the axios et call

Tags: javascript, reactjs

After getting the response from the get Axios call, I need to update the HTML but when updating the jsx like the following:

```
instance.get('/done.json').then(response => {
    task = response.data[Object.keys(response.data).pop()][props.match.params.id-1]
     console.log(task)
    // setseletectask(task)
        taskHmtl = (
        <Fragment>
            <p>{task.title}</p>
            <p>{task.done}</p>
        </Fragment>
    )
    }).catch(error=>console.log(error))
```

it doesn't update, so I have to create a new state and update it with the response value.
I need to know why the first approach didn't work correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> it doesn't update, so I have to create a new state and update it with the response value

Correct

> I need to know why the first approach didn't work correctly.

The component is already rendered, and assigning a value to a global variable doesn't trigger a re-render. This is why state exists in React.

Comment: I got your point, that's why we need the state to re-render the dom with the new values.but that means if I have initial value for the global variable it will be rendered then after updating the state the variable will be rendered with the new values,right ?

Comment: I assume so, but it isn't something I've had cause to test. Global variables are just a nightmare to deal with in general and are best avoided.